# show $F \in \operatorname{End}(V)$ , $P_F(0) \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow F$ isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

So this was my approach :

$F$ isomorphism $\Leftrightarrow \ker(F)=0 \Leftrightarrow \nexists v \in V$ with $v\neq 0$ such that $Fv=0$ $\Leftrightarrow \lambda:=0$ is not an eigenvalue of $F$ $\Leftrightarrow P_F(0) \neq 0$, where $P_F$ is the characteristic polynomial of $F$ and $F$ is endomorphism.

Did I miss something , or is the reasoning ok? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the scalar field? You may have some problematic (but not unfixable) steps in your reasoning. (Hint for a variant: what's the constant term of the characteristic polynomial?)

Comment: The scalar field is not defined in the question , i assume it's $\mathbb R$. Where is the invalid assumption?

Comment: I corrected to "problematic step". How do you go from "$0$ is not an eigenvalue" to "$P_F(0) \neq 0$"?

Comment: I think you might be missing a huge, important condition without which all the above is false: it must be $\,\dim V<\infty\;$ ...

Comment: @DanielFischer The step that $ \lambda$ is eigenvalue $\Leftrightarrow P_f(\lambda):=$ det$(F-\lambda I_n)=0$ was proved in my book

Comment: @DonAntonio yes. Sorry i forgot to mantion that. Thanks

Comment: @AmireBendjeddou Okay, if you can cite that, it's fine.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @DonAntonio: the condition that $\dim V<\infty$ is implicit in the fact that the characterisitic polynomial is defined: $\dim V=\deg P_F<\infty$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, the char. polynomial appears only in the very last part of that string of biconditionals in the OP: the first biconditionals are false if the space isn't finite dimensional.

Comment: The scalar field doesn't matter, as long as it is a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the actual question: your reasoning is perfectly in order (although the final "and $F$ is endomorphism" could be omitted, as it was assumed implicitly in all intermediate statements).

Answer (score 2):

Saying that there's no eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $F$ such that $\lambda=0$ is similar to say $P_F(0)\neq0$ so this not the expected answer, so to prove it:

Let 
$$P_F(x)=\det(F-xI)=(-1)^nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$$
the charaecteristic polynomial and since $P_F(0)\neq0$ then $a_0\neq 0$. By the Cayely Hamilton theorem we have $P_F(F)=0$ so
$$F\underbrace{\frac{1}{-a_0}\left((-1)^nF^{n-1}+a_{n-1}F^{n-2}+\cdots+a_1\right)}_{F^{-1}}=I$$
so we conclude.

Comment: I don't understand the above: "so to prove it"...to prove it *what*?

Comment: My question was if my reasoning was right. I'm not supposed to use he Cayley Hamilton theorem for this question. But i appreciate the alternative answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio I mean to prove that $P_F(0)\neq0$ imply $F$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is straightforward.  If $p_F(0) = \det(F) \ne 0$, then $F$ is invertible.  Conversely, $F$ being invertible implies the only solution to $F(v) = 0$ is $v = 0$, so $0$ is not an eigenvalue.

Comment: i don't have that information about the invertibility. The question was if my reasoning is ok.

Comment: @AmireBendjeddou An isomorphism is defined to be an invertible linear map.  Your reasoning is correct, but when writing a proof you should use complete sentences.

Comment: yes next time i will write full sentences with the details. I know that an isomorphism is defined to be an invertible linear map but i cannot use (at this point of my book) that : $p_F(0)=$det$(F)\neq 0$ then $F$ is invertible, but thank you for your help!!